# Why don't purely functional languages use reference counting?

Tags: memory-management, functional-programming, garbage-collection, reference-counting, purely-functional

In purely functional languages, data is immutable. With reference counting, creating a reference cycle requires changing already created data. It seems like purely functional languages could use reference counting without worrying about the possibility of cycles. Am is right? If so, why don't they?

I understand that reference counting is slower than GC in many cases, but at least it reduces pause times. It would be nice to have the option to use reference counting in cases where pause times are bad.

Comment: Reference counting is actually a garbage collection algorithm. So RC vs GC doesn't make any sence. Reference counting vs mark-sweep or a compacting collector is a better question.

Comment: As Brian and JaredPar say, circular structures can be created without mutability.  In fact, I'd say they're *more* frequently found in Haskell than any other language, thanks to the ease of handling them (hurray laziness).  Examples have been added to JaredPar's answer.

Comment: @Luke Quinane: When I say GC, most people do not think of RC. GC is generally assumed to mean mark-swep-like strategies.

Comment: @Zifre: When you say 'garbage collection', most people think of the truck that comes by to pick up their trash.  I don't think an argument from demographic popularity is really germane to the subject.

Comment: @chaos, surely a germane demographic is precisely relevant?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your question is based on a faulty assumption.  It's perfectly possible to have circular references and immutable data.  Consider the following C# example which uses immutable data to create a circular reference.

```
class Node { 
  public readonly Node other;
  public Node() { 
    other = new Node(this);
  }
  public Node(Node node) {
    other = node;
  }
}
```

This type of trick can be done in many functional languages and hence any collection mechanism must deal with the possibility of circular references.  I'm not saying a ref counting mechanism is impossible with a circular reference, just that it must be dealt with.

#### Edit by [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713)

In response to the comment... this is trivial in Haskell

```
data Node a = Node { other :: Node a }
recursiveNode = Node { other = recursiveNode }
```

and barely any more effort in SML.

```
datatype 'a node = NODE of unit -> 'a node
val recursiveNode : unit node =
    let fun mkRecursiveNode () = NODE mkRecursiveNode
    in mkRecursiveNode () end
```

No mutation required.

Comment: Your example still relies on modifying already created data (albeit in the constructor). I was not aware that this was possible in any purely functional languages though. Can you give a simple example in Haskell (if possible)?

Comment: @ephemient, thanks for the example. I'm kind of new to Haskell so forgive me for such a trivial question.

Comment: `Your example still relies on modifying already created data (albeit in the constructor).`... false claim. There is still no mutation in that example.

Comment: Data persistenci prevent cyclic references ... your example in Haskell is infinite recursion. Just disassemble it and you will see ... Start thinking functionally and stop spreading misinformation ...

Comment: what @Zifre is quite possibly alluding to is that immutability taken together with *strong initialisation semantics*, where references to a data structure instance that has not yet been fully initialised are disallowed, would not admit circular references

Comment: I feel like `other` is a really missleading name here.

Comment: Actually reference counting works fine when the only way to achieve cycle is the creation. Objects just need to be created with a shared reference counter.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but in your SML example, `recursiveNode` is not cyclic. It's infinite but not cyclic. the reference counter would have no problem working with it because every `NODE` evaluated is being generated as a new object on the heap. This is not the same as ocaml's `let rec cycle = 1 :: cycle` in which `cycle == List.tl cycle` (physically equal)

Answer (score 30):

Relative to other managed languages like Java and C#, **purely functional languages allocate like crazy**.  They also allocate objects of different sizes.  The fastest known allocation strategy is to allocate from contiguous free space (sometimes called a "nursery") and to reserve a hardware register to point to the next available free space.  Allocation from the heap becomes as fast as allocation from a stack.

Reference counting is fundamentally incompatible with this allocation strategy.  Ref counting puts objects on free lists and takes them off again.  Ref counting also has substantial overheads required for updating ref counts as new objects are created (which, as noted above, pure functional languages do like crazy).

Reference counting tends to do really well in situations like these:

- Almost all heap memory is used to hold live objects.
- Allocation and pointer assignment are infrequent relative to other operations.
- References can be managed on another processor or computer.

To understand how the best high-performance ref-counting systems work today, look up the work of [David Bacon](http://domino.research.ibm.com/comm/research_people.nsf/pages/bacon.index.html) and [Erez Petrank](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~erez/).

Comment: Actually it is possible to add a nursery to a reference counting collector: http://cs.anu.edu.au/~Steve.Blackburn/pubs/papers/urc-oopsla-2003.pdf

Comment: Hybrid collectors are definitely the future, and if anybody can make this work, Steve Blackburn can (especially when he has help from Perry Cheng).  That said, I'm not sure I'd be willing to extrapolate their Java results to a modern functional language.  Java's not too hard on the memory system.

Answer (score 11):

There are a few things, I think.

- **There *are* cycles**: "let rec" in many languages does allow "circular" structures to be created.  Apart from this, immutability does usually imply no cycles, but this breaks the rule.
- **Ref-counts are bad at lists**: I don't know that reference-counted collection works well with e.g. long singly-linked-list structures you often find in FP (e.g. slow, need to ensure tail-recursive, ...)
- **Other strategies have benefits**: As you allude to, other GC strategies are still usually better for memory locality

(Once upon a time I think I maybe really 'knew' this, but now I am trying to remember/speculate, so don't take this as any authority.)

Comment: Ref counting works fine with lists as long as you do it lazily: when an objects ref count goes to zero, it goes onto the free list, but you don't decrement the things it points to until it comes off the free list.  That way every operation is constant time (bound by the size of the largest object, not the length of the longest list).

Comment: let rec is a precise place to introduce shared reference counters

Comment: @OCTAGRAM Do you mean shared, like C++'s `std::shared_ptr`, or weak, like C++'s `std::weak_ptr`?

Comment: @MaxBarraclough Counter is shared between objects, not only between references. More like TAggregatedObject redirecting AddRef and Release to its master

Answer (score 11):

> Am is right?

Not quite. You can create cyclic data structures using purely functional programming simply by defining mutually-recursive values at the same time. For example, in OCaml:

```
let rec xs = 0::ys and ys = 1::xs
```

However, it is possible to define languages that make it impossible to create cyclic structures by design. The result is known as a *unidirectional heap* and its primary advantage is that garbage collection can be as simple as reference counting.

> If so, why don't they?

Some languages do prohibit cycles and use reference counting. Erlang and Mathematica are examples.

For example, in Mathematica when you reference a value you make a deep copy of it so mutating the original does not mutate the copy:

```
In[1] := xs = {1, 2, 3}
Out[1] = {1, 2, 3}

In[2] := ys = xs
Out[2] = {1, 2, 3}

In[3] := xs[[1]] = 5
Out[3] = 5

In[4] := xs
Out[4] = {5, 2, 3}

In[5] := ys
Out[5] = {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: +1 for saying "unidirectional heap".  This is what you need to Google to learn more about this topic. :)

Answer (score 9):

Consider [this allegory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI_koans) told about [David Moon](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=david+moon&hl=en&lr=&btnG=Search), an inventor of the [Lisp Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine):

> One day a student came to Moon and said: "I understand how to make a better garbage collector. We must keep a reference count of the pointers to each cons."
>
> Moon patiently told the student the following story:
>
> > "One day a student came to Moon and said: 'I understand how to make a better garbage collector...

Answer (score -7):

Reference counting is MUCH slower than GC because it's not good for CPU. And GC most of the time can wait for idle time and also GC can be concurrent (on another thread). So that's the problem - GC is least evil and lots of tries shown that.