# Is it possible to create a circular data structure in Scheme without mutation?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, reference-counting

I can create a circular data structure in Scheme like this:

```
(define my-pair (cons 1 1))
(set-car! my-pair my-pair)
```

Is it possible to create a circular data structure in Scheme without using mutation? (I am preparing a lecture on the limits of reference counting.)

Comment: My guess is that it's not possible, because Scheme is eager, but maybe you could do something funky with the Y operator.

Comment: so the answer seems to be: "no, unless you change the meaning of `cons`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @molbdnilo answer most scheme imeplemetation define `delay` and `force`,
that allow to create so called streams (defined in
[SICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs)).

```lisp
; The infinite list (1 1 1 ...
(define ones (cons 1 (delay ones)))

> ones
(1 . #<promise>)

> (force (cdr ones))
(1 . #<promise>)

(eq? ones (force (cdr ones)))
#t
```

`delay` and `force` can be implemented as macros that are just lambda expression. You can even write procedures like filter or map that handle streams.

EDIT:

Also defined by R7RS you can create real circular list with datum labels.

```lisp
(define x '#0=(a b c . #0#))
x
;; ==> #0=(a b c . #0#)
(eq? x (cdddr x))
#t
```

If Scheme fully support the R7RS spec it should allow to define and display circular list in the same way. Note that in Kawa Scheme it will print in a loop to display the circular list you need to use `(write x)`.

Comment: Thank you! This is simpler and purer than solutions using `letrec`.

Comment: @EllenSpertus I need to do also an update, because Scheme defined in R7RS also allow to create circular list with datum labels.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a lazy list with closures:

```
; The infinite list (1 1 1 ...
(define ones
  (letrec ((x (cons 1 (lambda () x))))
    x))

> ones
'(1 . #<procedure>)
> ((cdr ones))
'(1 . #<procedure>)
```

Identity check verifying circularity:

```
> (eq? ones ((cdr ones)))
#t
```

Answer (score 3):

By following a link to a related question ([Why don't purely functional languages use reference counting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791437/why-dont-purely-functional-languages-use-reference-counting?rq=1)), I saw a reference to `letrec`. That made me realize that I can indeed create a circular "data structure" in Scheme:

```
(letrec ((add (lambda (x y) (if (>= x y) (+ x y) (add2 y x))))
         (add2 (lambda (x y) (if (>= x y) (+ x y) (add y x)))))
  (add 1 5))
```